# How to resize the undo-tree-visualizer window?

Tags: emacs, undo, evil-mode

I  have been trying to automatically resize the undo-tree-visualizer window whenever it opens up in emacs. To fix this I have made a hook, the hook does resize the window however once the hook is ran the cursor ends up on the `*undo-tree*` window, to solve this I have to use the `(save-selected-window)` command however it did not work. I then decided to try and force emacs to go back to the previous window by using the `(evil-window-left)` function (I am using evil mode) however it only results in giving me this error:

Error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 1) 0)
  evil-window-left()
  (if (not (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*")) nil (select-window (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*")) (evil-window-set-width 45) (evil-window-left))
  undo-tree-hook()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook)
  undo-tree-visualizer-mode()
```

Code:

```
(defun undo-tree-hook ()
  "Hook to make the undo-tree-visualizer window to automatically resize to become smaller"
  (interactive)
  (unless (not (get-buffer-window undo-tree-visualizer-buffer-name))
            (select-window (get-buffer-window undo-tree-visualizer-buffer-name))
            (evil-window-set-width 45)
            (evil-window-left)))

(add-hook 'undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook 'undo-tree-hook)
```

Comment: Show more of the backtrace. You don't show the part that says which function wanted an arg but got none.

Comment: ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (1 . 1) 0)
  evil-window-left()
  (if (not (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*")) nil (select-window (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*")) (evil-window-set-width 45) (evil-window-left))
  undo-tree-hook()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook special-mode-hook undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook)
  undo-tree-visualizer-mode()```

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: I added the backtrace to the question

Comment: You can now see that `evil-window-left` expects an argument, but your code passes it no arguments. `C-h f evil-window-left` should also tell you what it expects. So you now have the answer to your question, no?

Comment: Yes I solved it by using `(save-excursion)` and `(evil-window-left 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Drew said, I needed to pass a parameter to the `evil-window-left` function and I also used `save-excursion` to save the point where I was on in the current buffer before I executed to the commands to switch to and resize the `*undo-tree*` buffer.

```
(defun undo-tree-hook ()
  "Hook to make the undo-tree-visualizer window to automatically resize to become smaller"
  (interactive)
  (unless (not (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*"))
    (save-excursion
            (select-window (get-buffer-window " *undo-tree*"))
            (evil-window-set-width 45)
            (evil-window-left 1))))

(add-hook 'undo-tree-visualizer-mode-hook 'undo-tree-hook)
```